# C: code generates a segfault non-cost point to string?

Tags: c

I'm trying to invoke the following code and it results in a segfault.  I understand this indicates the program is trying to access memory it doesn't have access to.  I see that the line `*b = *c` causes the problem, however it's my understanding this should be a valid operation.
    #include

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *b = "defg";
    char *c = "hijk";

    printf("%c,%c", *b, *c);
    fflush(stdout);

    *b = *c;

    return 0;
}

$ gcc -g -Wall test108b.c && ./a.out
$ ./a.out
d,hMemory fault(coredump)
```

UPDATE:
Using `x[]` defining an array of characters vs using a pointer to a character string literal works!  The following alternate code works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char b[] = "defg";
    char c[] = "hijk";

    char *bp = b;
    char *cp = c;
    while (*bp)
     *bp++ = *cp++;

    bp = b;
    while (*bp)
     printf("%c", *bp++);

    return 0;
}


gcc -g -Wall test108b.c && ./a.out
hijk
```

Does anyone know why the second version of the code works and the first does not?

Comment: You can't modify a string literal. So trying to set the value of a character in the string pointed to by `b` is not valid. (Just reading its value would have been fine.)

Comment: String literals are const. The compiler lets you assign a string literal to a non-const pointer for backwards compatibility. That doesn't change the fact that you now have a non-const pointer to a const string. Initializing an array with a string literal causes the program to copy the string literal into a non-const array. You can then change the contents of the array, if you wish.

Comment: Any reason why the core file didn't show this?

Comment: You need to supply gdb with both a symbol file and an executable file, along with the core file. The easiest way to do this is `gdb -se a.out -c core`. Alternatively, just run `gdb` and then use the two commands: `file a.out` and `core core`. Since you only gave it a symbol file, it didn't have enough information for an accurate backtrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your very first line is an error:

```
char *b = "defg";
```

String literals are read-only, and should be assigned to `const char*` pointers to reflect this.

If you want to initialize a `char` **array** (not a pointer) with a string, you can do that, and you can modify it:

```
char b[] = "defg";
```

Note that this is quite an exception and only works for initialization with a string literal. This won't work:

```
char c[] = b;
```

Comment: Do you know why gdb didn't give a backtrace?

Comment: @notaorb Welcome to C. When you do something bad, often "undefined behavior" happens. This might mean you get a nice error message, or a nice stacktrace in GDB, it might also mean it just bluescreens your PC. Sorry, there's no definite way to ensure you get a backtrace exactly to where you went wrong.

Comment: @orlp: This is C, not C++ :-) although that doesn't affect the idea behind your comment. But one might reasonably expect GDB to work anyway, and it will if you tell it enough. See my comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

String literals are read only except in the initialization of character arrays, but really things are a bit more complicated. This behavior depends on your compiler and architecture, but with gcc and x86 this seems to be the behavior. I believe this is for security reasons. There used to be a flag to enable the behavior you want, but that has been removed from gcc as well. Your best bet is to initialize your arrays as char arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char b[] = "defg";
    char c[] = "hijk";

    printf("%c,%c", *b, *c);
    fflush(stdout);
    *b = *c;
    char *bp = b;
#if 0
    while (*b)
     *b++ = *c++;

    while (*bp)
     printf("%c", *bp++);
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Also, I suspect that this is just a demo program to show the behavior you are asking about, but the best way to copy strings will be with something like strlcpy from the libbsd library (if you are on linux). It null terminates unlike less safe siblings strcpy and strncpy.

Here are some helpful compiler flags:

This flag will warn you if you make this error.

-Wwrite-strings

This flag will warn about comparing string literal memory addresses.

-Waddress

Hope that helps